# Вывод изображения вне локального сервера

Tags: html, xampp

Использую xampp для локального сервера. Возможно как-то вывести изображения с другого диска? Если запускаю index.html на рабочем столе, изображение отображается. Запускаю в локальном сервере и иконка отсутствия изображения.

```
<img src="file:///G:/folder/test-img.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, только в приделе области запущенного проекта можете изображения брать. Это ж с точки зрения безопасносности сделано... Что б если вы какую каку запустите, то максимум потеряете проект, а не всю систему.
Это на всех локальных серверах так.

Comment: Пришлось перенести сервер на другой диск